# Proof: the number of maximal cliques in a graph with boxicity $d$ is $\mathcal{O}((2n)^d)$

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for the proof of the following result

> The number of maximal cliques in a graph with [boxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxicity) $d$ is $\mathcal{O}((2n)^d)$

On the Wikipedia page and other papers where this result has been mentioned, they cite the following paper

> Roberts, Fred S. "On the boxicity and cubicity of a graph." Recent progress in combinatorics 1 (1969): 301-310.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find this paper anywhere. I'm looking for either access to this paper or a proof sketch for this result. I'm hoping to use the ideas within this proof to improve the bound for a subset of graphs with boxicity $d$.

Comment: [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=XAWFAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=boxicity) confirms that the article is in the conference proceedings "Recent Progress in Combinatorics" but doesn't display full pages. I think you'd have to go through an academic institution's library to access this.

Comment: I did happen to come across it in the Stanford library but unfortunately I do not have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually do a bit better and get a hard bound of $n^d$, not $O((2n)^d)$. Of course, for fixed $d$ as $n \to \infty$, $O(n^d)$ and $O((2n)^d)$ are the same...

The maximal cliques are obtained by picking a point $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and taking all boxes containing $x$. Though there seem to be infinitely many ways to do this, many of them give the same clique - without loss of generality, we may assume that each component $x_i$ of $x$ is the lower bound of the $i^{\text{th}}$ dimension of some box.

To prove this: suppose that a clique is formed by vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$, where $v_j$ is represented by the box $[a_1^j, b_1^j] \times \dots \times [a_d^j, b_d^j]$. Let $x \in \mathbb R^d$ be given by $x_i = \max\{a_i^1, \dots, a_i^k\}$. Then:

- in the $i^{\text{th}}$ dimension, $x_i \ge a_i^j$ for all $j$, by construction. In particular, $x_i = a_i^{j^*}$ for some $j^*$.
- in the $i^{\text{th}}$ dimension, $x_i \le b_i^j$ for all $j$; otherwise, if $x_i = a_i^{j^*} > b_i^j$, then $[a_i^j, b_i^j]$ and $[a_i^{j^*}, b_i^{j^*}]$ don't intersect, so $v_j$'s and $v_{j^*}$'s boxes don't intersect.
- Therefore $x_i \in [a_i^j, b_i^j]$ for all $j$, which means $x$ is contained in all $k$ boxes.

So the clique given by $v_1, \dots, v_k$ is contained in the clique of all boxes containing $x$; if the clique was maximal, it must *be* the clique of all boxes containing $x$.

There are $n^d$ ways to choose a point whose every component is the lower bound of some box. Not all of these $n^d$ points will give maximal cliques (some might not even be contained in any boxes) but all of the maximal cliques will be given by one of these points, so there are at most $n^d$ maximal cliques.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I was also wondering why we would have to use both upper and lower bounds. The way I understand it, the intersections of $k$ axis-parallel rectangles is also an axis-parallel rectangle which should have a lower bound, this would imply that every maximal clique has a lower bound. Inversely, every $x$ we construct using only lower bounds can correspond to at most one maximal clique (If an $x$ corresponded to two distinct maximal cliques, the union of the two maximal cliques is also a maximal clique, contradicting the original assumption).

Comment: I was just wondering why the bound is not $\mathcal{O}(n^d)$ i.e. just the number of $x$s constructed using the lower bounds

Comment: It seems like you're right and $O(n^d)$ also works. I was dubious and wrote out a more careful proof (see my edit), but I cannot see any flaw in it, and after looking through some papers I can't find any argument otherwise, either. (Most people appear to claim this without proof, or to cite an earlier paper that does so, but I haven't been able to track down all citations.)

Comment: I'm sorry, It didn't strike me that when $d$ is fixed, $\mathcal{O}((2n)^d)$ and $\mathcal{O}(n^d)$ are the same, which you pointed out in the edit. Thanks for the help!