# Class of graphs with superpolynomial / subexponential number of maximal cliques

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request

It is a [classical result of Moon & Moser](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760024) that the maximum number of maximal cliques in a graph with n vertices is $3^{n/3}$. There are several similar examples with exponentially many maximal cliques, such as the [Turan graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $T(2n,n)$, sometimes called the ["cocktail party graph,"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CocktailPartyGraph.html) having $2^n$ maximal cliques.

On the other hand, several classes of graphs are known to have polynomially many maximal cliques. These include, for example, [graphs with bounded boxicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181281/proof-the-number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-graph-with-boxicity-d-is-mathcalo) (having at most $n^b$ maximal cliques where $b$ is the boxicity), [chordal graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334190) (at most $n$ maximal cliques), [graphs with bounded degeneracy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5440) (at most $(n-d)3^{d/3}$ where  $d$ is the degeneracy), [planar graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334190) (at most $7n/3 -6$), and [intersection graphs of convex polytopes in Euclidean space](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X18301458) (having $O(n^{dk^{d+1}})$, where $d$ is the embedding dimension and $k$ is the number of facets of the polytopes).

**Question:** Are there any classes of graphs known to have superpolynomial, but not exponential, number of maximal cliques? For example, $O(n^{\log n})$, $2^{O(\sqrt n)}$, or $2^{O(\log n)^k)}$ for some $k \geq 2$. I think such functions are also sometimes called [quasipolynomial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasi-polynomial_time)

**Edit:** After reading more about asymptotics, I see that superpolynomial, quasipolynomial, and subexponential functions each have slightly different meanings, but for my purposes, any one of them would work.